# Android UI elements null when returning from intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent

I have added a button to a fragment that starts a new activity. It works, but when returning from the intent, I have no access to the ui elements any more (from the activity that holds the fragment) - they are null.

What is the proper way to handle this setup? I suspect the problem to be related to the activity life cycle.

I have the following configuration:

- Activity A includes two fragments (Fragment 1 and Fragment 2)
- Fragment 1 has a button to start a new Activity B. The intent is given activity (Activity A) as an argument.
- When returning from Activity B, Activity A cannot access the ui elements inside Fragment 1 and Fragment 2 anymore.

[image]

Comment: How are you accessing the views in the Fragments?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Directly, just using its name.

Answer (score 0):

This block initiates Second Activity from the A fragment. And it didn't cause an error.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

The rest of the code is default.